# How to convert 21-03-18 14:01:03.000000000 AMERICA/TORONTO into 2021-03-18 14:01:03.000-04:00

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Please help me to convert input "21-03-18 14:01:03.000000000 AMERICA/TORONTO" which is in TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE datatype to output "2021-03-18 14:01:03.000-04:00" in Oracle.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: please, also edit the question subject.

Comment: @jvnd edited..can you please help me with the answer?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I assume both the input and the output are `timestamp with time zone`; it is not clear why the output has fractional seconds when the input does not. Also, it seems you want to present the result in a different time zone than the input (converting from Toronto to India), but without changing the time-of-day? That is exceptionally unusual, did you actually mean that, or were you lazy and didn't actually compute the ***correct*** expected result, from the given input? Or are you just correcting an incorrect time zone (time is OK, time zone is wrong)?

Comment: @mathguy- Sorry its my bad. Please check now. yes both input and output are in timestamp with time zone.

Comment: Both are the same timestamp with time zone. Only the string representation is different. Are you saying that when you **SELECT** the value, it is displayed in the first format, and you want it displayed in the second format? If it's only for displaying, you can `alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3tzh:tzm'` and all timestamps with time zone will be *displayed* in the format you requested (but they will remain in `timestamp with time zone` data type, which is good). If you really need to convert to string, use `to_char(..., format_model)` with the same format.

Comment: I don't want to alter my session. I am using in SELECT statement. Can you please use Dual table to convert this as an example? Please convert in to_char format as an output.

Answer (score 1):

As stated so, so, so  many times before, if your "input' is a column or variable of type TIMESTAMP (any variant of that) then the data is *NOT*  "21-03-18 14:01:03.000000000 AMERICA/TORONTO".  Oracle DATE and TIMESTAMP types are *internal, binary* structures.  The "format" is a string representation for humans to read.

As your question reads, the answer is simply to use the TO_CHAR function to convert that internal TIMESTAMP to whatever format you wish to see:

```
select to_char(my_timestamp_column,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from my_table;
```

See the SQL Language Reference for more format elements.

```
SQL> create table my_test (my_date TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
  2                        )
  3  ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into my_test values (systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select to_char(my_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff6TZH:TZM')
  2  from my_test
  3  ;

TO_CHAR(MY_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:
--------------------------------
2021-03-26 14:29:21.570971-05:00

1 row selected.

SQL> --
SQL> drop table my_test purge;

Table dropped.
```

Comment: @EdStevens- can you please provide me an example in dual table with this conversion?

Comment: I have tried this...select to_char(to_timestamp_tz('21-03-18 14:01:03','dd-mm-yy HH24:MI:SS','nls_date_language = english'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:sssssss tzd') AS TIME from dual; But getting output "2018-03-21 14:03:5046303 EDT"

Comment: Please help me to convert input "21-03-18 14:01:03.000000000 AMERICA/TORONTO"  into  to output "2021-03-18 14:01:03.498+0530" in Oracle sql. Please use dual table for answer.

Comment: Using an example with the dual table would just confuse things because I would have to start with a string representation of a timestamp.  Your actual problem is in formatting a column that is already a timestamp. TO that I already gave you a perfect example.  All you need to do is modify the format mask to add the fractional seconds and time zone.  And that is documented in the SQL Language Reference.

Comment: Thanks EdStevens

Answer (score 1):

OK - it seems that your input is a timestamp with time zone (which is displayed to you in your "input" format, but that is irrelevant for the question).

You want to convert it to a string, in your chosen format.

This can be done as follows:

```
with
  inputs (ts_tz) as (
    select to_timestamp_tz('21-03-18 14:01:03.000000000 AMERICA/TORONTO',
                           'rr-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff TZR')
    from   dual
  )
select to_char(ts_tz, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3tzh:tzm') as result
from   inputs
;

RESULT                       
-----------------------------
2021-03-18 14:01:03.000-04:00
```

Comment: Thanks mathguy ur the best!!!